# Creating an Array-like class in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python so please don't blast me.
I come from Java and i just studied class creation in python.

In a code a found this, i'll explain in words :

There is an object x of class X, if a call zip(x) i get an iterator of tuples, but i can also call x.shape to get a list of other elements,different from the tuples' ones.
Now, what i think is that there is something implicit in the class definition, for what when i call zip(x) a special method is called.And x.shape is a simple attribute of the class.What do you think?

It will be fantastic if you show me how can i implement a class like this. Thanks

Comment: which class `X`?

Comment: Please share your code with an example.